Error in Next.js Prisma e-commerse store. [ Server ] Error: Invalid `prisma.category.findMany()` invocation:
This is fullstack pizza e-store.I've complited 30% or more of it. But with error i cant complete it.
GITHUB
https://github.com/nikitodeon/NextPizza-ErrorProject.git
ERROR on localhost:3000 :
[ Server ] Error: 
Invalid `prisma.category.findMany()` invocation:


Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(PostgresError { code: "42P05", message: "prepared statement \"s0\" already exists", severity: "ERROR", detail: None, column: None, hint: None }), transient: false })

Source
app\(root)\page.tsx (16:22) @ async Home

  14 |
  15 | export default async function Home(/*{ searchParams }: { searchParams: GetSearchParams }*/) {
> 16 |   const categories = await prisma.category.findMany({
     |                      ^
  17 |     include: {
  18 |       products
  19 |       : {


Error in Terminal:
▲ Next.js 15.1.0
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Network:      http://192.168.0.103:3000
   - Environments: .env

 ✓ Starting..
 ✓ Ready in 3.7s
 ○ Compiling / ..
 ✓ Compiled / in 7.8s (1328 modules)
[TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null] {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: [TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null] {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection:  [TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null] {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
 ✓ Compiled in 2.9s (615 modules)
 GET / 500 in 10831ms
 ○ Compiling /favicon.ico ..
 ✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 850ms (728 modules)
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 1040ms
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 21ms
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 261ms

app/(root)/page.tsx
import {
  Container,
  Filters,
  Title,
  TopBar,

  // Stories,
} from "@/components/shared";
import { ProductsGroupList } from "@/components/shared/products-group-list";
import { prisma } from "@/prisma/prisma-client";

// import { Suspense } from 'react';
// import { GetSearchParams, findPizzas } from '@/shared/lib/find-pizzas';

export default async function Home(/*{ searchParams }: { searchParams: GetSearchParams }*/) {
  const categories = await prisma.category.findMany({
    include: {
      products
      : {
        include: {
          ingredients: true,
          items: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="mt-10">
        <Title text="Все пиццы" size="lg" className="font-extrabold" />
      </Container>

      <TopBar
        categories={categories.filter(
          (category) => category.products.length > 0
        )}
      />

      {/* <Stories /> */}

      <Container className="mt-10 pb-14">
        <div className="flex gap-[80px]">
          {/* Фильтрация */}
          <div className="w-[250px]">
            {/* <Suspense> */}
            <Filters />
            {/* </Suspense> */}
          </div>

          {/* Список товаров */}
          <div className="flex-1">
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-16">
              {categories.map(
                (category) =>
                  category.products.length > 0 && (
                    <ProductsGroupList
                      key={category.id}
                      title={category.name}
                      categoryId={category.id}
                      items={category.products}
                    />
                  )
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}


prisma/schema.prisma
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider  = "postgresql"
    url       = env("POSTGRES_URL") 
    directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
}

model User {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    fullName String
    email    String    @unique
    password String
    role UserRole @default(USER)
    verified DateTime
    provider String?
    providerId String?

     cart             Cart?
      orders           Order[]
     verificationCode VerificationCode?   
 createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Category {
    id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
    name     String    @unique
    products Product[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Product {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    name     String
    imageUrl String

ingredients Ingredient[]
items ProductItem[]

category Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
categoryId Int

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model ProductItem {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    price     Int
    size      Int?
    pizzaType Int?

    cartItems CartItem[]

    product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
    productId Int
}


model Ingredient {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    name     String
    price    Int
    imageUrl String

    products  Product[]
     cartItems CartItem[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Cart {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int?  @unique

     items CartItem[]

    token String

    totalAmount Int @default(0)

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
model CartItem {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    cart   Cart @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
    cartId Int

    productItem   ProductItem @relation(fields: [productItemId], references: [id])
    productItemId Int

    quantity Int @default(1)


    ingredients Ingredient[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
model Order {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int?

    token String

    totalAmount Int
    status      OrderStatus
    paymentId   String?

    items Json

    fullName String
    email    String
    phone    String
    address  String
    comment  String?

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model VerificationCode {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int  @unique

    code String

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())

    @@unique([userId, code])
}


enum OrderStatus {
    PENDINGQ
    SUCCEEDED
    CANCELLED
}
enum UserRole {
    USER
    ADMIN
}

prisma/prisma-client.ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

declare global {
  var prismaGlobal: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
}

export const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma;
 

.env (example)
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://postgres:<password>@<host>:6543/postgres?sslmode=require&supa=base-pooler.x"
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://postgres:<password>@<host>:6543/postgres?sslmode=require&supa=base-pooler.x"
SUPABASE_URL="https://<your-supabase-url>.supabase.co"
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL="https://<your-supabase-url>.supabase.co"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://postgres:<password>@<host>:5432/postgres?sslmode=require"
SUPABASE_JWT_SECRET="<your-jwt-secret>"
POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY="<your-anon-key>"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="<password>"
POSTGRES_DATABASE="postgres"
SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY="<your-service-role-key>"
POSTGRES_HOST="<host>"
SUPABASE_ANON_KEY="<your-anon-key>"
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL="/api"

I've tried to solve the problem many times.Nothing helped. All files on my github
